# Multiple Outcome Binomial Regression R

Tags: r, statistics, glm, multivariate-testing

It is possible to use `cbind` to specify multiple outcomes for plain `lm` regressions as such:

```r
set.seed(11)
df <- iris %>%
  mutate(var1 = sample(c(0L,1L), 150, replace = TRUE),
         var2 = sample(c(0L,1L), 150, replace = TRUE))

df %>%
  lm(cbind(var1, var2) ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length, data = .) %>%
  coef()

#                      var1        var2
# (Intercept)  0.5010092855  1.17035845
# Sepal.Width  0.0015431925 -0.16210972
# Sepal.Length 0.0001607519 -0.03218511
```

Can this be done with a binomial `glm`? If not, how should one perform the intended analysis (MANOVA)?

```r
df %>%
  glm(cbind(var1, var2) ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length, family = binomial, data = .) %>%
  coef()

# (Intercept)  Sepal.Width Sepal.Length 
#  -1.3886130    0.3587017    0.0588412
```

The `glm` above does not appear to be producing a matrix of coefficients as with lm, the output is the same format as if only one outcome is specified.

Comment: No, a two-column vector on the left hand side of a binomial glm is interpreted as an array of counts (first column for TRUE and second column for FALSE)

Comment: @AllanCameron Any ideas for how to perform the intended analysis, then?

Comment: It's not a big deal to get round this. Effectively the two-columns-on-the-left method gives the same result as running the regression twice (once for var1 and once for var2), so `cbind(coef(lm(var1 ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length, data = df)), coef(lm(var2 ~ Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length, data = df)))` gives the same result as the cbind method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not this way. `lm()` allows this because the specific structure of linear regression allows the linear regression equations to be solved simultaneously (and efficiently) for several response variables.  The trick doesn't work for generalized linear models.

To do this with `glm()` you have to set it up yourself, e.g.

```r
ff <- function(var) {
   f <- reformulate(c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"), response = var)
   glm(f, data = df, family = binomial)
}
(c("var1", "var2")
   |> purrr::map(ff)
   |> purrr::map(coef)
   |> bind_cols()
)
```

(you still need to sort out the row/column names)

or

```r
library(broom)
(c("var1", "var2")
   |> setNames(nm = _)
   |> purrr::map(ff)
   |> purrr::map_dfr(tidy, .id = "respvar")
   |> select(respvar, term, estimate)
   |> pivot_wider(names_from = "respvar", values_from = "estimate")
)
```

`lme4::lmList()` handles the case where the data are in long format:

```r
library(broom.mixed)
library(lme4)
(df 
   |> pivot_longer(c(var1, var2))
   |> lmList(formula = value ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width | name,
             family = binomial)
   |> coef()
   |> t() ## transpose
)
```

There are lots of other questions on SO that do variants of this (run `lm()`/`glm()` for different response variables, on elements of a list, etc etc), but I can't find them easily.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks Ben. I'm curious as to why anyone uses the cbind-on-the-left method in lm. Is there any reason to do it other than to reduce repetition in the code? I mean, that's a good enough reason on its own, but presumably it always gives the same result as two separate regressions?

Comment: It's considerably more efficient (everything can be done with a single QR decomposition). Also, some multivariate-specific methods are available (`methods(class="mlm")`, e.g. `SSD`, `mauchly.test`, `estVar`)

Comment: Thank you, Professor Bolker. So we have to split the models instead of making a hypothetical `mglm` model. Do you know of any good references or packages for how to test variable significance and coefficients across separate binomial glm models like this? For example, does sepal length contribute to both var1 and var2?

Comment: I'd make that a separate [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) question ...